# Order of execution in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a file `A` and want to create a file `B` from it, replacing same variables during the make process.
The variable names are stored in `vars`.

A minimal Makefile looks like this:

```
vars = var1 var2 var3

var1 = AAA
var2 = BBB
var3 = CCC

default:
    cp A B
    $(foreach var,$(vars),$(shell sed -i "s/$(var)/\"$(value $(var))\"/g" B))
```

And file A looks like this:

```
blabla var1 blabla
blabla var2 blabla
blabla var3 blabla
```

When I execute `make`, I get the output

```
sed: can't read B: No such file or directory
sed: can't read B: No such file or directory
sed: can't read B: No such file or directory
cp A B
```

The copy statement is executed *after* the `foreach`! I can correct this by setting up a seperate target, say `copy`, only place the copy command in there and make `default` depend on `copy`.

But why??? Why is the order of execution within a rule not strict?

What am I missing?

ps:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Can't really *explain* it at this point, but the traditional way of using functions like `$(foreach ...)` is to set *variables*, not in recipees like you did. Not sure if that is even supported in any way. Trying to find the relevant piece of documentation.

Comment: Sorry, cannot find chapter and verse on this. But all the examples in the make documentation use functions only in variable definitions, not in recipees.

Comment: @DevSolar: yes, I took a shot and it worked... maybe, the `$(foreach ...)` idiom creates different process/thread and doesn't wait?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(shell)` is a *make* function. It executes at *make* time (in this case at recipe expansion time). That happens **before** the recipe is executed.

The `$(foreach)` happens at that time also.

You just don't want `$(shell)` here at all. You want the `$(foreach)` to output a single (long) shell recipe line that make can execute normally. (Make sure to terminate the output command with a `;` to make it shell-legal.)

```
default:
    cp A B
    $(foreach var,$(vars),sed -i 's/$(var)/"$(value $(var))"/g' B;)
```

I also switched to single quotes to avoid the need to escape and because there isn't anything in that string that the shell needs to expand. make does all the variable expansions here.

Comment: actually, I had that but without the final `;`. Didnt work that way, works now!

Comment: Yup, without the `;` your shell sees one giant command which often isn't what you want (but can be if you are putting a list of arguments together).